# dlsym causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++

So I've been trying to get symbols from a local dylib but whenever I try to do anything I just get a seg fault and I'm unsure why this occurs. I've seen this done in other programs and they work fine, so I know it works but I just can't seem to do it :(. Any help is appreciated.
Cheers

```c++
typedef void (*func_t)();
func_t testFunction;


template<class type>
type findSymbol(string dylib, string symbol)
{
    void* handle = dlopen(dylib.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);

    if(!handle)
    {
        debug(dlerror());
        return nullptr;
    }

    // Reset errors
    dlerror();

    type sym = (type)dlsym(handle, symbol.c_str());

    const char* dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if(dlsym_error)
    {
        debug(dlsym_error);
        dlclose(handle);
        return nullptr;
    }

    sym(); <--- Executes fine

    dlclose(handle);

    return sym;
}

int main()
{        
    // Example 1
    testFunction = findSymbol<func_t>("./test.dylib", "hello"); <--- Seg fault

    // Example 2
    func_t f = findSymbol<func_t>("./test.dylib", "hello"); <--- Fine
    f(); <--- Seg fault

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think the note about closing the handle here is correct, but just in case someone has another type of error: 
do objdump -T <.sofile> and look at the symbols. 
I fixed my problem by annotating the name of the fn declaration, example:

 fn void onStart() asm ("onStart");
Otherwise onStart got "mangled" and had a prefix _ZonStart whatever.  I could reference the mangled symbol by name, but obv not great idea.  I could also fix by marking the function "extern C".  I need to look into the implications of either method, but in practice that seemed to solve related issues I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official POSIX `dlclose` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlclose.html):

> Once a symbol table handle has been closed, an application should assume that any symbols (function identifiers and data object identifiers) made visible using handle, are no longer available to the process.

That means, once you called `dlclose` you can no longer use any functions from the module.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turns out that I was truncating the returned 64bit pointer from dlopen into a 32bit value and trying to link a symbol with that value.

For Example:-

```
#define HANDLE int;
HANDLE library = (HANDLE)dlopen("libname.so");
HANDLE symbol = (HANDLE)dlsym(library, "symbol");
```